# elasticsearch dynamic query - Add another field to each document returned

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river, elasticsearch-plugin, pyelasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

What I need is very simple, but I am unable to find how to do it in Elasticsearch, possibly because of the complexity of what is required to be done.

Input (two sample JSON documents)

```
{ "car" : 150, "bike" : 300 }

{ "car" : 100, "bike" : 200}
```

What I want in return is that when I fire a search query it returns me the documents with an extra field `inventory` which is defined as the sum of number of cars and bikes. And in the sorted order.

Sample Output:

```
hits: [
   { "car" : 150, "bike" : 300, "inventory": 450},
   { "car" : 100, "bike" : 200, "inventory": 300}
]
```

Is it possible to do something like this in elasticsearch? (I assume using dynamic scripting)

Comment: You could create a third field when the data was inserted, or also use [a script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444966/elastic-search-find-sum-of-two-fields-in-single-query).

Comment: http://blog.qbox.io/elasticsearch-aggregations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did this using script fields. Refer:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html

sample query:

```
query: {
...
},
script_fields: {
  inventory: {
     script: "doc['car'].value + doc['bike'].value"
  }
}
```

This would result in a separate fields column with each hit as:

```
fields: {
    inventory: [450]
}
```

But, since I also wanted this to be sorted, I ended up using the sort:

```
query: {
...
},
sort: {
    _script: {
        script: "doc['car'].value + doc['bike'].value",
        type: "number",
        order: "desc"
    }
}
```

which returned me a sort field with each hit, such as:

```
sort: [450]
```